# HTTP status 407: Proxy authentication required Error when calling web service

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication, proxy

I have spent two hours on this error "HTTP status 407: Proxy authentication required Error " when calling a web service, my code is like following

```
WebProxy oWebProxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(ProxyServer, ProxyPort);
oWebProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ProxyUser,ProxyPassword,ProxyDomain);
oserv.Proxy = oWebProxy;
oserv.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(theusername, thepassword);
```

I have verified that the proxy address, user id password are all correct, and I could access the web service thru the IE in same pc, but when I run the code with VS, the error keeps popup.
I have tried the `UserDefaultCredentials=true` as well, but no luck.

Any idea?

Comment: Watch the traffic in Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) and see whether the client attempts to respond to the 407 challenge by providing credentials, or whether it doesn't attempt to add the creds at all.

Answer (score 6):

Popping a`<defaultProxy />` element into in app.config / web.config under `<system.net>` with `useDefaultCredentials="true"` may well do the job.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to run the application in on same network where the webservice is installed